# Parse on item click listener null exception

Tags: java, android, parse-platform, null

```
  using parse , testing on emulator and getting null pointer exception ,
```

I think that the meal isn't connecting with the adapter , that's why I cant access it and it returns null? can anyone help me with code , and correct it or tell what's the problem. thanks

```
public class MealListActivity extends ListActivity {

    private ParseQueryAdapter<Meal> mainAdapter;
    private FavoriteMealAdapter favoritesAdapter;
    private Meal meal;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getListView().setClickable(true);

        mainAdapter = new ParseQueryAdapter<Meal>(this, Meal.class);
        mainAdapter.setTextKey("title");
        mainAdapter.setImageKey("photo");

        getListView().setOnItemLongClickListener(
                new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent,
                            View view, int position, long id) {
                        mainAdapter.getItemId(position);
                        ChangeRating(meal);
                        return false;
                    }

                });

        // Subclass of ParseQueryAdapter
        favoritesAdapter = new FavoriteMealAdapter(this);

        // Default view is all meals
        setListAdapter(mainAdapter);

    }

    protected void ChangeRating(Meal meal) {
        String x = meal.getRating();
        if(x.isEmpty()){
            meal.setRating("5");
            updateMealList();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_meal_list, menu);
        return true;
    }

    private void updateMealList() {
        mainAdapter.loadObjects();
        setListAdapter(mainAdapter);
    }
```

I am trying to set the rating of a meal inside the Meal class in parse , like in code , checking if the rating cell is empty and then inserting a rating inside the cell , but the logcat shows that the if(x=meal......isEmpty) null pointer exception

```
    01-28 12:21:30.810: E/AndroidRuntime(1470):     at com.parse.mealspotting.MealListActivity.ChangeRating(MealListActivity.java:52)
01-28 12:21:30.810: E/AndroidRuntime(1470):     at com.parse.mealspotting.MealListActivity$1.onItemLongClick(MealListActivity.java:37)
01-28 12:21:30.810: E/AndroidRuntime(1470):     at android.widget.AbsListView.performLongPress(AbsListView.java:2580)
01-28 12:21:30.810: E/AndroidRuntime(1470):     at android.widget.AbsListView$CheckForLongPress.run(AbsListView.java:2530)
01-28 12:21:30.810: E/AndroidRuntime(1470):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
01-28 12:21:30.810: E/AndroidRuntime(1470):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-28 12:21:30.810: E/AndroidRuntime(1470):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-28 12:21:30.810: E/AndroidRuntime(1470):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
01-28 12:21:30.810: E/AndroidRuntime(1470):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-28 12:21:30.810: E/AndroidRuntime(1470):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-28 12:21:30.810: E/AndroidRuntime(1470):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
01-28 12:21:30.810: E/AndroidRuntime(1470):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
01-28 12:21:30.810: E/AndroidRuntime(1470):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

EDIT

```
   @Override
                    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent,
                            View view, int position, long id) {
                        // mainAdapter.getItem(position);
                        meal = mainAdapter.getItem(position);
                        if (meal.getRating().isEmpty()) {
                            meal.setRating("5");
                            updateMealList();
                        }
                        return false;
                    }
```

I tried that but still getting the same problem .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't set the meal reference to any Meal object before the call to ChangeRating and it obviously is null.

Should it be

```
meal=this.getListAdapter().getItem(position);
```

Comment: I tried that , with some fixes , I was able to get this code , but still getting the same problem .
see the edit

Comment: this.getListAdapter().getItem(position);